# Integrating Linux soft + hard reboot

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, reboot

I read [here](http://major.io/2009/01/29/linux-emergency-reboot-or-shutdown-with-magic-commands/)  that using below command we can simulate hard reboot on Linux system:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

But I wanted to add some soft reboot feature before the above command is executed such as `SIGTERM`, `SIGKILL` etc which are issued on soft reboot. Can any one suggest how can i do it using bash or C/C++. Also what are steps followed while doing soft reboot on Linux system?

Answer (score 1):

Simulating or using the SysRq key sequences to trigger a soft reboot is not necessary in most of the situations, you can instead simply use the `reboot` command in bash. In a C program, I would use `system("reboot");`. Of course you will need to be root to reboot the machine.

**Edit**: If you want to call these command after the necessay cleanup of a soft reboot, your best option is probably to call yourself the corresponding reboot scripts in `/etc/rc6.d`.

This would be distribution-dependant, on a debian or ubuntu it would look like this:

`/etc/rc6.d/S20sendsigs
/etc/rc6.d/S40umountfs
/etc/rc6.d/S60umountroot`

You can choose the scripts that you think are needed (networking, killing the daemons...).

Comment: I don't want to do soft reboot but want to ensure that the background work done before reboot is completed and that I want to call above 2 commands to perform hard reboot.